# How to insert value from barcode reader into form input when the form page is minimized?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have developed an attendance taking system with PHP and I am running it on localhost. The system is like this:

Suppose a student has a bar coded ID card and to take his attendance there is a barcode reader and the form I have developed. The barcode reader I have automatically pushes the submit button so as soon as I trigger the barcode reader's button, the value from the barcode is taken and after some processing some values are inserted into the database.

Now it is working fine, but the problem is every time I take the attendance I need to open up the form first and then take the attendance. (I need to take attendance several times a day.) I was wondering if there is any way to take the attendance without having to open up the form repeatedly.

If there is no solution for it, is it possible to keep the form page minimized and take attendances while someone is working on computer (doing something else)?

Comment: This is more about the barcode reader that you are using than any specific technology.  What macros are available?  How advanced is the barcode reader?  What would you like it to display if the student isn't allowed in the class?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how your barcode reader works, mostly. I infer from your description that:

- The barcode reader, when activated, sends the data and emulates <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- The data is populated in the active input element, or, I assume, anywhere that keyboard characters are accepted. Can be tested by opening a text editor and seeing if the data is accepted followed by a newline.

Next, you have a web application, which doesn't run in the background. Technically it's still active on the browser even while minimized, but once minimized the browser is no longer the application with focus, and therefore the data doesn't go to it.

So you have two problems:

1. You need a way to get data from the barcode reader without affecting the current application. In other words, if someone is using a word processor, you don't want the barcode reader to suddenly insert random information in their work.
2. You need an application or service to "listen" to the barcode reader and interact with the database. You could write it so that it pops up a dialog or something in the event of a misread, incorrect attendee, etc.; however if the computer needs to be used for something else while attendance is being taken, that could be annoying.

Hopefully your barcode reader vendor has some information available to you which can help you solve problem 1. As for problem 2, I don't have any advice except to consider rewriting your application as a service or application that you can minimize.

Comment: Thank you JYelton, for your reply. After reading your answer I just figured it out that I have to build another software with a different programming language to do the same task ; additionally which will be running as a service. But the problem is I have no knowledge on other programming languages other than some basic PHP. However, the barcode reader that I have bought is very cheap( Chinese Probably- around $200) and doesn't have any instructions for developers in the manual. I googled for some information but didn't find any. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the scanner comes with software that in one way or another, would let you execute a command when a barcode scan event occurs.

then just craft the command

```
php attendance.php "...barcode data..."
```

I bet the scanner comes with documentation that would be at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply. The barcode reader that I have bought is very cheap( Chinese Probably- around $200) and doesn't have any software or any instruction for developers. I googled for some information but didn't find any. Doesn't matter.. probably I need to build another software which will be doing the same task but this time running as a service. :)